# Pressure in the pipe when the pool is draining out

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity

I have a question: the situation is as follows: There is an open pool (in blue) to which a pipe is connected. The pressure above the pool is equal to the air pressure = 1 bar.
In normal configuration the valve from the pipe is closed and thus the pressure in point B is equal to the air pressure + ρgH (hydrostatic pressure). There is no flow through the pipe.

In case there is a rupture of the pipe at the height of the valve, water will siphon from the pool via the pipe at a velocity v.
My question is how can you calculate the pressure in point A?

I think the pressure in point A is calculated as follows:

P<sub>a</sub>+ $\frac{1}{2}$ρv<sub>a</sub>²+ρgL=P<sub>b</sub>+$\frac{1}{2}$ρv<sub>b</sub>²+ΔP<sub>friction</sub> where v<sub>a</sub>=v<sub>b</sub> and thus:

P<sub>a</sub>+ρgL=P<sub>b</sub>+ΔP<sub>friction</sub> where P<sub>b</sub> is equal to the air pressure (1 bar) due to the break.

P<sub>A</sub>=P<sub>B</sub>+ΔP<sub>friction</sub> - ρgL

ΔP<sub>friction</sub>=f<sub>D</sub>*$\frac{L}{D}$*$\frac{ρv²}{2}$

However, my friend does not agree with me and says that P<sub>a</sub> is equal to P<sub>b</sub>. So who is right?

[image]

Comment: The driving force for fluid flow is a pressure difference.  That means that you are right.

Comment: P friction should not be used if we use bernoulli's theorem. Because it is conservation of energy.

Comment: Therefore Pa=Pb-pgL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pressures at points a and b are not equal.[image]

pressure at B = pressure at A + pgL